# How to add ASCII char 29 delimited in string?

Tags: c#-4.0

i wants to add ASCII char 29 delimited in string as group separator. How can i use in my code. Please help me with some c# code.
Thanks

Comment: What's not working for you about it at the moment?

Answer (score 4):

you need to typecast it

console.write((char)29);

you can do it in string like:  "name" +(char)29+" \nphone" + (char)29